# Update new Table SortOrder from 2 older data tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I UPDATE ut.SortOrder from both dt1.SortOrder and dt2.SortOrder?

```
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM dbo.UpdateTable ut
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataTable1 dt1
ON (dt1.PrimeID = ut.PrimeID AND dt1.SecondID = ut.SecondID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataTable2 dt2
ON (dt2.PrimeID = ut.PrimeID AND dt2.SecondID = ut.SecondID)
WHERE ut.PrimeID = 8746
```

We are basically merging 2 tables and so there are sort orders in both data tables. But only 1 data table will match at a time.

DataTable1 content could have sort orders of 1 and 3 whilst DataTable2 could have sort orders of 2 and 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  It uses `coalesce` to determine the first non-null `sortorder`.  If not found, it sets the sort order back to itself.

```
UPDATE ut
SET ut.SortOrder = COALESCE(dt1.sortorder, dt2.sortorder, ut.SortOrder)
FROM updatetable ut
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataTable1 dt1
    ON (dt1.PrimeID = ut.PrimeID AND dt1.SecondID = ut.SecondID)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DataTable2 dt2
    ON (dt2.PrimeID = ut.PrimeID AND dt2.SecondID = ut.SecondID)
WHERE ut.PrimeID = 8746
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/852ff/1)